# Meaning behind variable transformation

Tags: real-analysis, limits

At times we change variables to ease computation for example while solving indeterminate forms of limits which have repeating pattern on applying lopital's rule. For example,$\left\{\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}},\frac{x+\frac{1}{x}}{x-\frac{1}{x}}\right\}$. Here $e^x$ is relaced by x and we get appropriate result. So, I thought to plot both expressions, [image]

with the blue representing first equation and other color the next equations. So, both are depicting similar kind of behavior. So is this the idea behind it ?

Comment: Yes, geometrically that is the idea. The only issue is that pictures could be misleading and that is why they don't constitute a formal proof. Formally what you are using is the property of limits: If $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=L$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow b}g(x)=a$, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow b}f(g(x))=L$.

Comment: In your case $f(x)=\frac{x+1/x}{x-1/x}$, $g(x)=e^x$.